# Using Data Filters on Synchronized Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

We have created sync Data Extensions of Salesforce objects such as Contact, Transactions and store location.  We would like the ability to create filtered data extensions on this data for email sending and Ad Studio audiences.

Support has suggested we query (not filter) on sync Data Extensions as it causes errors.  End users need the ability to use drag and drop because of no knowledge of SQL.

Reports is not an option because our exclusion lists are data extensions and they cannot be used in conjunction with a report.

Only solution we can come up with is create a query to replicate the sync DE's or create an import of the same information.  Wondering what is the use of sync DE unless they are only for customers that write SQL only.

Would love your suggestion on how we could have access to all this information with drag and drop filter feature in Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience with Filters is, they have limited use when you work with a normalised data model. They can be used for filtering a single Sendable Data Extension, but they are being challenged when working with multiple data relationship and large datasets.

Whenever I want to make life easier for clients getting their data from Synchronised Data Extensions, I build a flattened/denormalised data model, where I join multiple Data Extensions into a single one, selecting key parameters across all the synchronised data. This can be e.g. preferred store, last purchase date, CLV, average basket size - where I join order data (assuming you are using such data) on Contact object. This creates a single record for each consumer with derived values generated by my query, are stored individual DE fields. I ensure this supports most of the segmentation use cases, because any corner cases will indeed require working with SQL. Otherwise, this single Sendable Data Extension can easily be filtered and used for multiple segments.